# How to read / update connectTimeout & ReadTimeout in an OkHTTP Interceptor?

Tags: java, interceptor, okhttp, connection-timeout

Why are connectTimeout & ReadTimeout available on OkHttpClient only? Is the "okhttp3.Request" not the right place?

Also,

- How can I read / update the connectTimeout & ReadTimeout in an "okhttp3.Interceptor"?
- Also, is it possible to know in an "okhttp3.Interceptor" that the call is a sync / async call?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following way:

HTTP client 3:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
```

HTTP client 2:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.setReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.setWriteTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

1. [Reference link okhttp3](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/ConfigureTimeouts.java)
2. [Reference link okhttp2](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.7.5/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.java#L206)